# How to display true for a certain range of digits?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How to display true for a certain range of digits?

I want to return true with an interval of numbers 20-30, except 21 and 28 after the first three characters, tell me how to do this?

```
const onHandleCorrectNumber = e => {
  const numbers = e.target.value // +500(MYINTERVAL)-5555-55
  phone.slice(0, 4)
  if(numbers === 21 || numbers === 28) return false

  return numbers.length === 2
}
```

UPD:

```
+500(19)-5555-55 // false 
+500(20)-5555-55 // true 
+500(21)-5555-55 // false 
+500(22)-5555-55 // true 
+500(28)-5555-55 // false 
+500(30)-5555-55 // true
+500(31)-5555-55 // false
+500(32)-5555-55 // false 
...
```

Comment: Provide an example

Comment: What do you mean "after the first three characters". Please give some examples of input and expected output

Comment: Do you have an example of input and expected output that would clarify your requireents?

Comment: +500(19)-5555-55 // true
+500(20)-5555-55 // true
+500(21)-5555-55 // false
+500(22)-5555-55 // true
+500(28)-5555-55 // false
+500(30)-5555-55 // true
...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming all your phone numbers are going to follow same format i.e. +ddd(dd)-dddd-dd. & you are trying to separate the interval from the phone number.

You can either search for regex, which would have super clean solution.

or you javascript's `substring()` function. Something like this:

```
myInterval = phone.substring(5,7)
```

Also you need to add more conditions to check whether the interval is between 20-30.

```
 if(myInterval >= 20 &&  myInterval <= 30 && myInterval != 21 && myInterval != 28)
```

Should do the trick.